Can someone please explain to me why these sudden closures are not an obvious example of a moderator backlash?
About 14 hours ago, I pointed out how it’s a pretty horrid “mistake” to close an answer that others found useful (10 upvotes, the “mistake” was admitted to only after being called out, “we all make mistakes” was used as an excuse, etc).
Given that this moderator is presumably pretty popular (given that he’s probably been on this site for extremely long), this got a lot of backlash, which is fine by me, since I’m only interested in saying what I think is true, and not if people like me, or even agree with me (since the truth doesn’t depend on popularity).
But then curiously, about 4-5 hours ago, the same moderator decides to close about 20+ questions by his own personal discretion (a noticeable amount of which were by me). They were almost all given the reason for closure as “needs clarity” even though a good chunk of them did not have 4 close votes, and many seemed clear enough for other users to participate in. A new user has already complained about this, while an established user also wants a thread to track closure to make this process more transparent given that another very established user (KristianBerry) left because of this.
Look, I understand that certain users are more liked and others are disliked. I don’t care about how many people dislike me. But what I do care about is if questions are being closed correctly. If you want “ah, I’m just annoyed by this user” as a valid reason to close a question, make that part of the rules. As of now, it isn’t.
I do not think it is a coincidence that the same moderator who was called out then decides to all of a sudden close many questions through his own personal opinion when a series of closed questions have not rapidly occurred at any time in recent history.
This is not to say that every single one of the closed questions did not deserve to be closed. Of course not. But given that a huge chunk of them were closed right after me talking about this moderator’s “mistake”, with some of them also randomly re opened a few hours after, such as this one (where another moderator probably realized that the original moderator is closing this incorrectly) suggests that this closing process is being done based on whims and a potential backlash rather than anything substantial. It becomes even more pressing to call this out given that they were closed by the same moderator who has already made mistakes like this.

Geoffrey closed questions by many users, not just you. Only he can explain why, but it does not appear to be aimed at any specific person.

@causative I’m sure it’s a complete coincidence that he decided to close a barrage of questions right after I called him out for his “mistake”. I didn’t say that it was necessarily only targeted at me but my comment likely antagonized him to produce this barrage

@Syed. I was not antagonised by anything you had said. I gave reasons for my closure of questions. I would not be doing my duty as a Moderator if I were to react emotionally in a negative kind of way to anything that you or anyone else on this site had said. I have not done any such thing in my seven years as a member of PSE, and yesterday's closures were no exception.  Please accept my reassurance on this point.

@Syed Approximately half of your lifetime questions asked have been closed - I just went back and counted everything through the second page of questions on your "all questions" page. Is it more likely, then, that a recent string of closures is a brand-new witchhunt deployed against you by a mod for some reason we can't identify, or that you just happened to write a few questions that happened to get closed in a row? Flipping a coin a dozen times and getting four or five tails is actually not unlikely. What would be an obvious example of mod abuse is if one person VTCed all your posts.

@controlgroup you should learn more about probability theory. If you did, you’d realize that your logic can explain away any discrepancy or any conspiracy. How “likely” or “unlikely” an event is depends on how you frame the event. There’s a lot of selection bias that goes into this process

While I don't believe that moderators are above emotional reactions or don't make mistakes, I would like to reject the notion that Geoffrey Thomas is retaliating against you or anyone else. Every moderator is a volunteer, and has a set of unique views, and I have yet to have an interaction with a moderator that would suggest they are petty and vindictive.
We have two cultures on this site, and sometimes they work at cross-purposes. One is a culture of credentials, professionalism, and academic rigor, and the other is a culture of passionate and curious amateurs, and it happens sometimes it is difficult for us amateurs to meet the standards of the more rigorous contingent. Balanced against that is the rejection of facilitating amateurs to reshape their language or to go out of the way to help rehabilitate questions.
Never take closure personally, because it is not easy to write a good question. Vagueness and ambiguity inhere to words. This site deals with a lot of technical detail. If your question isn't well formed, use it as an opportunity to figure out what you don't know. Every criticism is either off the mark, in which it can be ignored, or it is on the mark, in which case its an opportunity to learn and grow.
If Geoffrey Thomas popped in after his teatime, fished through some posts, and flexed some VTC might, the site is better off for it. There are mechanisms to deal with VTC, and it might help to remember that this site functions more like an intellectual meat grinder than a school. It is, after all, a Q&A site for serious philosophical discourse. There are other more tolerant sites like thephilosophyforum.com, but the tradeoff is that it's tougher to identify whose responses are quality responses.
This site IS NOT meant to chit chat about philosophy. It just isn't. If you work the comments a little, or you find someone who wants to use chat.stackexchange.com, so be it. But you should be aspiring to higher technical ability. My advice is take a look at Conifold's, Allegranza's, Klocking's, and Geo. Thomas's answers to see what high quality questions and answers look like.

Conifold’s “answers” are opinionated comments that he doesn’t respond to when inaccuracies are called out

@Syed Given the difference in the average user's answers and his reputation,  and the quality of his non-comment answers, his comments are preferable to most other's answers.  I don't always agree w everything he posts myself, but this board has enough room for a difference of oppinion, and your mission shouldn't be too correct everyobe you disagree with.
